# Net Core 3.0 Linux Azure Web App IHttpContextAccessor have null context

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, cloud, blazor

I have an issue in production with my Blazor Server application and the IHttpContextAccessor with Identity.

When I try to access the HttpContext, this one is null in the Azure Web App but not in my local machine.

I use this gateway to access the Context :

```
public class AuthenticationGateway : IAuthenticationGateway
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private UserManager<User> _userManager;
        public AuthenticationGateway(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public bool IsLogguedIn()
        {
            return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetLogguedUser()
        {
            return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
        }
    }
```

I use a B1 plan webapp under Linux working with Kestrel.

Comment: do you have `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: There is also a extension method which can be used:  `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

Comment: I added the AddHttpContextAccessor but change nothing. I will try with the TryAddSingleont method :)

Comment: Check if you have enabled websockets in the Azure App. I have a feeling that it's off based on being able to access the context locally, but not deployed in Azure.

Comment: @viveknuna works with tryaddsingleton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the below code in the Startup.ConfigureServices method

`services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`